# Does Eurail Continuous Global pass offer unlimited trips?

Tags: tickets, eurail

I can't find the answer to this simple Q:

For example, if I buy a Eurail Global Continuous pass for 3 months ($2200ish at this time), can I make, say, 1000 trips on regional train services in all Eurail countries (i.e. no supplements or reservation fees to pay) and only have spent $2200 at the end of 3 months?

Or are there some limits, like one ride per day?

Comment: Are you aware of what services it is and isn't valid on, and which one need compulsory reservations and supplements?

Answer (score 3):

There are no limits to the pass. You are allowed to take as many trips all across the EuRail countries. This is valid even for trains which require supplements or reservations. As long as you have the valid supplement or reservation, there is no limit to the pass on those trains as well.

I spent 3 months with the pass traveling across most of Western Europe and some countries in eastern Europe and never came across an issue even once. We must have easily taken over 100 trains in that period and I'd say it was a great deal.

Ideally they ask you to fill in each journey on the pass booklet but in my experience with a Global Pass there was no check of any sort with regard to whether I actually filled it out or not (I didn't).

Comment: that is the case for the non-highspeed trains. You must buy a reservation for the highspeed trains and often times that can be expensive.

Comment: @monksy Yes, I mentioned that, and no the reservation are not *very* expensive usually. Typically most highspeed trains (Italian TrenItalia, Spain Renfe AVE etc.) need 10 euro reservations. French TGV needs 3 euros IIRC and German ICEs don't need any.

Comment: The german ICE tickets do need reservations. [But they're about 4.50 or better] the thalyis trains are about 39e a piece. http://uk.voyages-sncf.com/en/pass/seat-reservation

Comment: @monksy That is not correct, they are optional. Please read the Eurail Document on [this](http://www.eurail.com/plan-your-trip/guide-eurail-train-reservations/how-do-i-book-my-reservations/train-reservations-germany). And yes night trains or special trains like Thalys can be more expensive. I have never traveled on a Thalys so honestly I wouldn't know.